# Gophish API request is blocked : "header ‘authorization’ is not allowed" (Javascript request)

Tags: api, httprequest, gophish

I am using the Gophish API for the first time.

I can't get the list of the sending profiles through a simple Javascript HTTP request. Firefox display this error message :

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
``https://MY_GOPHISH_SERVER_URL:3333/api/smtp``. (Reason: header ‘authorization’ is not allowed according to header  ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).
```

Here is my request code :

```
fetch("MY_GOPHISH_SERVER_URL:3333/api/smtp", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Authorization : MY_GOPHISH_API_KEY
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(error.message))
}
```

What could I try ? Is there a way to edit Gophish CORS policy ?

Thanks.

Julien

Additional information :

- The campaigns made from Gophish browser interface work well.
- If I try the same request with POSTMAN, it works only if I disable the SSL certificate verification.
- The SSL certificate is valid (I own it and it is announced as valid by browsers)

Comment: Sounds like that endpoint needs to support cors

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I finally found the origin of my problem :
The Gophish API library documentation (coded in Python by the Gophish team) says that one should disable SSL verification ... BUT ...

BUT ... it does not work for a Javascript request and it can not because the 'authorization' header can not be present in a simple GET request (as mentioned by the error message given).

THE SOLUTION IS : simply write the api_key in the URL as usual

```
/api/campaigns/?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY (hidden in an environment variable of course)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think they have issue in their api because I have tried everything to disable ssl certificate verification but still api does not save the result.